# while converting kivy app to apk getting this error with python 3.10,kivy 2.1.0

Tags: python, android, kivy

while converting kivy app to apk getting this error with python 3.10,kivy 2.1.0

[INFO]:    Stripping libraries in private dir
[INFO]:    Frying eggs in /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/_python_bundle__arm64-v8a/_python_bundle/site-packages
[INFO]:    <- directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Copying in SDL2 .java files from: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL/android-project/app/src/main/java/org/libsdl/app
[INFO]:    -> directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp
[INFO]:    Saving distribution info
[INFO]:    <- directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Your distribution was created successfully, exiting.
[INFO]:    Dist can be found at (for now) /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp

```
# Build the application #1
# Copy application source from /content
# Create directory /content/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /content/main.py
# Package the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1020, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 93, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 106, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 205, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 1088, in build_package
    version = self.buildozer.get_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 667, in get_version
    'version.regex and version.filename conflict with version')
Exception: version.regex and version.filename conflict with version
```

Comment: you say you use python 3.10, but your traceback says python 3.7... peculair

Answer (score 0):

try commenting out the `version.regex` and `version.filename` lines in your buildozer.spec file and set the same value as your version.